# Al ejecutar la aplicación en el móvil, se cierra automáticamente

Tags: java, android, activity

Cuando ya termino mi app y la instalo en mi teléfono, esta nunca se abre, hace el intento pero se cierra automáticamente.

Estoy creando una App que pueda jalar una imagen de mi galería. Aquí les dejo el código que estoy aplicando:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Camera;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Surface;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

ImageView imagen;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    imagen= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
}

public void onclick(View view) {
    CargarImagen();
}

private void CargarImagen() {
    Intent intent =new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            intent.setType("image/");
    startActivityForResult(intent.createChooser(intent,"seleccione la aplicacion"),10);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode==RESULT_OK){
        Uri path=data.getData();
                imagen.setImageURI(path);
    }
}
```

Comment: Tiene que agregar el mensaje de error que te muestra en el **Logcat** para saber donde se origina el error.

Comment: Es muy importante como menciona @DavidMinaya agregues el mensaje de error desplegado en el LogCat de otra forma la causa por la que se cierre la aplicación tienen muchas razones y estariamos tratando de adivinar :(, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Alex.

El problema lo tienes en el supuesto botón que tienes en el layout y su escuchador.

Por lo que veo tienes el método `CargarImagen(){}` que seguro haces su llamada con un `android:onClick="CargarImagen"` en el propio `layout` y luego haces la llamada de este método `CargarImagen(){}` en un `onClick` cuando no tienes porqué.

Tienes que **quitar este método** y su llamada del interior y ya debe funcionar.

```
public void onclick(View view) {
    CargarImagen();
}
```

---

Deja el MainActivity así y te funcionará..

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageView imagen;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        imagen = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);

    }

    public void cargarImagen(View view) {
        Intent intent =new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        intent.setType("image/");
        startActivityForResult(intent.createChooser(intent,"seleccione la aplicacion"),10);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri path = data.getData();
            imagen.setImageURI(path);
        }
    }
}
```

## Resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ayúdanos a conservar la calidad de la información en el sitio, contestando preguntas que estén basadas en lo definido en el  [help], específicamente [ask]. Revisar [answer]. **En este caso como puedes dar soluciones pero ¿como puedes saber que se esta llamando CargarImagen() desde un layout? el OP no ha especificado eso**

Comment: Lo he supuesto @Jorgesys. Llevas razón en que dicho método `CargarImagen()` no lleva como parámetro el View, pero me ha llevado a suponerlo al hacer el llamamiento en el onClick. No obstante que comente @Alex Prins y salimos de dudas y editamos lo que haga falta. Saludos!

Comment: Leído lo del centro de soluciones y entendería que se borrase mi respuesta. ;)

Comment: Esperemos a que el OP aclare @DiegoLoL de hecho si se especifica que el método recibe como argumento (View view) es que puede ser llamado desde el layout, como tiene el código debio ser : "android:onClick=onclick", mejor esperemos y modificas tu respuesta, que pudiera ser correcta.